# Serializing a Nested Struct to send/recv in MPI

Tags: c, serialization, mpi, flatbuffers

Basically I'm creating a parallel program to calculate a julia set image of +50000 by 50000 pixels and I'm using MPI and PNG lib to do so. I have a struct of

```
typedef struct Block
{
    int size;
    int place;
    png_bytep *rows;
} block;

block knapsack;
png_bytep *row_pointers;
```

and an allocate function of

```
void allocate()
{
    row_pointers = (png_bytep *)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * height);
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        row_pointers[y] = (png_byte *)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * width);
}
```

I have this function to create a 'knapsack' which is a block of row_pointers that i can distribute to other processes.(I will combine the functions later when I solve this message passing problem.

```
void pack(int index, int size)
{
    knapsack.rows = (png_bytep *)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * size);
    knapsack.size = size;
    knapsack.place = index;

    for (y = 0; y < size; y++)
    {
        knapsack.rows[y] = (png_byte *)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * width);
        knapsack.rows[y] = row_pointers[index + y];
    }
}
```

Then I want to do something like

```
MPI_Send(&knapsack, sizeof(knapsack), MPI_BYTE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


MPI_Recv(&knapsack, sizeof(knapsack), MPI_BYTE, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

to send a block of these pointer to a bunch of nodes to do calculations on. It will eventually be tested on 128 cores.
The problem is I'm having a lot of trouble sending nested structs around the system and after printing out the contents with printf("%x", knapsack.rows[0]); I can see they dont match after being sent. I've been looking into I and realizing because my pointers are not in a continuous block it's not sending properly. I've been looking into serializing my knapsack and come across flatbuffers and protocol buffers. These seem overly complicated for this and it's been hard to find a good tutorial on it. My other option seems to be MPI_Pack() but I'm not sure how bad the time increase will be as the whole objective is to push this as high as possible and do it quickly. Does anyone have any advice on the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

You don't have a true 2D array. You have a 1D array of pointers to rows which are 1D arrays of pixels (e.g. `png_bytep` is a pointer to an array of `png_byte` pixels).

This can be slow because of the extra pointer indirection. Unless your functions operate strictly on rows.

*Possibly* better to have a true 2D array of pixels (e.g.):

```
typedef struct Block {
    int size;
    int place;
    int width;
    int height;
    png_byte *data;
} block;

block knapsack;
png_byte *img_data;

void
allocate(int height,int width)
{

    knapsack.height = height;
    knapsack.width = width;
    knapsack.size = sizeof(png_byte) * height * width;

    knapsack.data = malloc(knapsack.size);
    img_data = knapsack.data;
}
```

Your `MPI_Send` [and `MPI_Recv`] just send the `struct`.

But, after a [non-zero] rank receives it, the `png_byte *data;` pointer is *meaningless* because it is an address within the address space of the rank 0 process.

Sending the struct tells the receiver the *geometry* (i.e. height/width) and other metadata, but it does *not* send the actual data.

Although there [probably] is some more advanced `MPI_*` calls, here are examples that use the simple `MPI_Send/MPI_Recv` ...

Sender:

```
// send geometry and metadata (the .data pointer will be useless to receiver,
// but that's okay)
MPI_Send(&knapsack, sizeof(knapsack), MPI_BYTE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// send the data matrix
MPI_Send(knapsack.data, knapsack.size, MPI_BYTE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Receiver:

```
// receive geometry and metadata (the .data pointer will be useless to us,
// but that's okay)
MPI_Recv(&knapsack, sizeof(knapsack), MPI_BYTE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// allocate space to receive the data
knapsack.data = malloc(knapsack.size);

// receive the data matrix
MPI_Receive(knapsack.data, knapsack.size, MPI_BYTE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The above assumes that you want to send the *entire* array to each [worker] rank. This is the simplest.

But, after you get that working, you may want to use `MPI_Scatter/MPI_Gather` instead to send partial/submatrices to each worker rank. That is, each rank only operates on a 2D subwindow of the full matrix.

Of course, you *could* still use *row* pointers, but the actual calls that transfer `knapsack.data` would need to be a loop that has a separate call for each `row`

---

For some additional information on how to split up the data for performance, see my recent[!] answer: [Sending custom structs in MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75844188/5382650)

*Side note:* If your nodes will be on the same physical processor system (e.g. you have a 128 core machine) and all cores can map/share the same memory, you might be better off using `pthreads` or `openmp`. Certainly, the overhead would be less and possibly the program would be more cache friendly. YMMV ...

Comment: Thanks! after many hours of debugging finally got a working solution. Will try your recommendations on scatter and gather as well. Next set is load balancing. Unfortunately we can't use pthreads and maybe can use openmp because it will run on a cluster.  Should have read the first sentence more carefully as that's how I realized the problem haha